# Dimmable range on one circuit is different to another. Why?

Tags: lighting, led, dimmer-switch

We've recently had some dimmable spotlights installed in our dining room. We have a setup where we have 3 lights off one switch, and 6 on a second switch. The lights were not dimming very much, maybe to about 50%. We assumed it was usual for spots like this and we weren't too worried about the range.

Lately we noticed that one bulb on the 3 light circuit was blinking intermittently (it's generally set to the lowest brightness setting) I thought that to see if it was the bulb or not I'd swap the bulb with another on the same circuit.

Here's the funny thing. When I did this, the dimming range of the 3 lights has improved dramatically, going all the way from barely visible in the day time at it's lowest to full brightness at it's highest?!

Why has this happenned?

I am now in the situation where one half of the room dims to about 50%(the 6 light circuit) and the other all the way to 1%(the 3 light circuit). I want to get the other circuit dimming in the same way, but not sure what to change!

Very confused !!

[image]

Comment: Are these incandescents? If not what are the make/models of the various light bulbs?

Comment: Hi Harper, they're all the same make/model Led spotlights, Led and Gu10 220-240v 50hz.   I'll add a picture of the box!

Comment: I took the liberty of rotating your picture, and adding *double* carriage returns between each paragraph so they render properly in this platform's markup.

Comment: It sounds like it may be a difference in the dimmers.  They're not all the same (unless they are :))   It's certainly not an overload problem, not at 5 watts/bulb.

Comment: it's _mostly_ the dimmer. a better/newer one should give you a better range. Specifically, it relates to the holding current of the triac, and it being too high. The last bulb you swapped draws more current than the one it replaced, so the triac can stay on longer before there's not enough current to pin the gate open, and that makes the other bulbs nice and dim.

Comment: Ok thanks Harper, I did wonder why it missed my change of paragraphs!

Comment: The odd thing is that they are ALL the same bulbs, and they are both the same dinners - installed at the same time.

Comment: And when I changed the bulbs position in the circuit it made that same circuit behave differently.

Comment: My dimmers have an adjustment to the low level. The adjustment slider is exposed when I pry off the cover.